# change epoch to ( epoch year and Juilan day fraction )

Tags: two-line-elements

[image]

the question asks you to make two line element it give you the given information and also everything is answered **but the one thing i don't understand in here is how do the change the Epoch 29 sep 2010 18:00:00:00.000 to 10272.41666666. i need someone to explain this to me in detail.**

Comment: have you done any checking of your own, on this site or elsewhere? Where, in your study, have you actually run into a problem?

Answer (score 3):

The example you posted is erroneous. The format of the "Epoch Year & Julian Day Fraction" is `yyddd.ffffffff`, where `yy` is the last two digits of the year, `ddd` is the day number of the year (sometimes called Julian day; do not confuse this with the concept of Julian dates), and `.ffffffff` is the UTC time of day as a fractional number of days. So 10272.41666666 is not the correct representation of 2010 September 29 at 18:00:00 UTC. It instead corresponds to 2010 (10 means 2010) September 29 (September 29 is the 272nd day of the year in a non-leap year) at 10:00:00 UTC (0.4166666 = 5/12, or 10/24).