Two line element. Change epoch to epoch year and Julian day fraction
How to do we change this epoch 29 sep 2010 18:32:00.000 to Julian day fraction. I know that the 10272 are the last digits of the year and the day but I want to know how do we get the Julian day fraction. Which is the decimal numbers.

Welcome to the site! This is a coding question which I'm sure has been answered on the original stack exchange, how is this related to space exploration?

This is exactly the same question asked here https://space.stackexchange.com/q/65757/6944 It must be in homework somewhere.

Duplicate of change epoch to ( epoch year and Juilan day fraction )

Welcome to Stack Exchange! This might (or might not) be helpful in Stack Overflow: Convert TLE times (decimal days) to seconds after epoch

see also Time, UTC, Julian Date, TLE epoch - how are they related quantitatively? and my favorite How to obtain UTC of the epoch time in a satellite TLE (two line element)?
